# Compare time and run macro

Tags: excel, vba

Current Time    Target Time
9:32:28 AM  5:32:00 PM

I have two time as mentioned above. Current time is the system current time and Target Time is user input time.
When both the time matches I want the macro to run automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The First block initiates the macro.

```
Sub Alarm()
    Application.OnTime "17:32:00", "MacroName"
End Sub

Sub MacroName()
    MsgBox "Macro is Running"
End Sub
```